# Trying to create an array from input whilst in a loop - Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, loops, gets

I am trying to create a programme that asks the user for a number, the programme keeps asking the user for a number until "stop" is entered at which point the sum of the numbers is returned.

The code sort of works but I realise that the first puts/gets.chomp is outside of the loop and is not being added to the array. I dont know how to implement this, any help thoughts would be greatly appreciated!

```
array = []

puts 'Give me a number'

answer = gets.chomp

until answer == "stop"
  puts 'Give me a number'
answer = gets.chomp
  array.push(answer)
end

array.pop

array
```

Comment: Why do u need input before loop? You can just set `answer = nil` before loop and all must be fine

Comment: Welcome to SO! You're extremely close--I recommend trying to work it out the rest of the way!

Comment: Why are you using an array?  Since the goal is to output the sum of the numbers, just start with `sum = 0` and keep incrementing it by the input as long as the input is numeric.  There's no need to store all the inputs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a situation like this.

```
do something
determine if we should stop
do something else
repeat
```

For this sort of fine control use a [`loop`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/Kernel.html#method-i-loop) to repeat until you [`break`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/doc/syntax/control_expressions_rdoc.html#label-break+Statement).

```
# Initialize your list of numbers.
numbers = []

# Start a loop.
loop do
  # Get the answer.
  puts 'Give me a number'
  answer = gets.chomp

  # Stop if the user wants to stop.
  break if answer == 'stop'

  # Store the number after checking that it is a number.
  numbers.push(answer)
end

p numbers
```